confusion about the definition of a subbasis for a topology by Munkres
By Munkres's Topology, a subbasis $S$ for a topology on $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ whose union equals $X$. The topology generated by the subbasis $S$ is defined to be the collection $T$ of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $S$. Besides, the collection B of all finite intersections of elements of S is a basis.
Suppose that $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$.
Then $S = \{\{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}\}$ is a subbasis since $\{1, 2\} \cup \{2, 3\} = \{1, 2, 3\} = X$ and $B = \{\{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{2\}\}$ whose elements are all intersections of elements of $S$.
Then the collection of all unions of elements of $B$ (which are finite intersections of elements of $S$) generated by $S$ is $T = \{\{2\}, \{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$.
But this $T$ is not a topology since empty set is not in it.
Is there anything that goes wrong or did I misunderstand? How do I obtain an empty set here?

The topology $T$ is $\left\{\bigcup_{k\in Y}k|Y\subseteq B\right\}$, which includes $\bigcup_{k\in\emptyset}k=\emptyset$ as $\emptyset\subseteq B$. So the topology does include the empty set.

the empty set is not an element of B. I still don't understand why a union of elements of B can be the empty union. Is it a definition or something?

The empty union is a union of $0$ elements of $B$ and is empty.

is it correct to say that k belongs to empty set?

There is no $k$ in the empty set, so the union has to be empty.

so, there is also an empty intersection of elements of S that can generate the empty set in B, right?
